# Location conversion

Tags: excel, location, format, latitude-longitude

If I have a location in the following format:

```
N51 46.981 W1 36.145
```

Is there an easy way to convert this to latitude / longitude? It doesn't really matter what it's written in as I need to run a script to convert a fair few of these. Ideally I would do it in a Excel / Numbers spreadsheet. My attempts recently came from using the `MID` command in Excel to grab the data into the following:

```
51:46:981
01:36:145
```

And then multiply them by 24 to get a latitude or longitude value. I'm fairly confident that this is incorrect as it seemed to lose accuracy. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Using google maps and searching for the first value above I get the result:

```
51.783017, -1.602417
```

This is essentially what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you asking for a formula to go from `N51 46.981` to `51:46:981`?

Comment: No, I'm asking for a forumla to go from N51 46.981 W1 36.145 to 51.783017, -1.602417.

Comment: Not a programming (VBA) question. Better suited to Super User

Comment: @brettdj I suppose that [formulae are a form of programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76767/179508) and superuser is more for "how do I create a pivot table" type of questions which only use the UI... My point being that it is quite subjective.

Comment: If you'd like I could write this as a VBA function? ;)

Comment: RE: Closure. I disagree that this is "unlikely to help any future visitors". The answer below is exactly what was required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the first one for example is `51.783017 = 51 + 46.981/60`.

Including the numbers extraction from the original string, the corresponding formulae in Excel could look like this (I am not using `mid` as the number of digits are not known: the degrees could be 1 to 3 figures for example):

[image]

And the results are:

[image]